# How to get system network status using dbus in Qt or Linux signals

Tags: c++, linux, qt, networking, qnetworkaccessmanager

For long I have been trying to get the system network status using Qt. I have a project that determines the network status using signals in Linux systems.

I have tried the `QNetworkConfiguration`, `QNetworkSession`, `QNetworkConfigurationManager`. But all of these classes only detect the network connection status while the network cable is plugged in or plugged out or network adapter is off. If we disconnect a purticular network interface like "ethernet" it still shows status as "connected" or "online". Is there any solution like using dbus or using system signals to get the network status of current network access.

My current solution is pinging in regular intervals but it takes more resources and is not a good solution.

Comment: Just to make sure (since Qt is cross-platform): you only need a solution for Linux?

Comment: ya currently I only need solution for the Linux.If you can provide a solution that would work in cross-platform it would be grateful too..